# Deploy Visual Studio Team Services (aka VS Online) build to an on-premises IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, azure-devops

What are the options for deploying a web-application that is built daily using Visual Studio Online (and hosted controller) and its new build definitions to an on-premises IIS behind a firewall?

If opening up the firewall, would it be possible to add some kind of WebDeploy-build step to the Visual Studio Online build? Haven't seen any WebDeploy build steps for now though...

...or could we write a PowerShell script running daily on the IIS-server that fetches the output of the daily build from Visual Studio Online? If that's possible, how can those files be accessed?

...or could something like OctopusDeploy help out here?

would like to refrain from having to set up an on-premises build controller.

Answer (score 1):

VSO Agents are lightweight and easy to setup if you have a server available.  Octopus Deploy integrates nicely most on premise scenarios.

That said, if you still want to keep hosted builds, Octopus would still work.

Create a VSO build definition and include [OctoPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OctoPack/).

Pick a hosted Nuget Server, presumably with a private repo subscription. A couple of options are MyGet and Artifactory.

In "MSBuild Arguements" include the parameters.

```
/p:RunOctoPack=true
/p:OctoPackPublishPackageToHttp=http://nugetrepoofyourchoice.com/nuget/packages
/p:OctoPackPublishApiKey=$(NugetAPI)
/p:OctoPackPackageVersion=$(Build.BuildNumber)
```

"NugetAPI" is actually a user defined variable (name of your choice) that references a Secret build variable. You will get this API Key from your Nuget Repo vendor.

On premise, in your Octopus installation, you would define your hosted Nuget feed as an external feed.

In your deployment project, it would pull the Nuget package from your hosted repo.

VSO pushes to hosted Nuget feed and Octopus pulls from the hosted Nuget feed.

Answer (score 0):

These feature are coming for VSO and were announced at Build. You will be able to deploy on-premises without needing to open a firewall port using agents.

While this is still in the works you can use Release Management for Visual Studio 2015 to pull the bits from VSO and deploy locally.

Comment: While licensing could well change, RM currently requires test pro or enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

Octopus deploy would work for this in a couple of ways.

1) Install a tentacle on the IIS server (either polling or listening will work depending on where you install octopus manager)

or

2) Install the main octopus deploy on a machine that has WebDeploy access to your IIS server, and use the custom library MS Deploy script

Getting the package to the main octopus deploy machine could be a bit tricky. Easiest way would be setting up a MyGet server and have the octopus server check it periodically, that way you don't need to open up firewalls to the public.